# Can iPad be hacked if password's security is questionable?

Tags: security

Is it possible for a "family member" that knows my passwords and has had access to my iPad to control my iPad from a different location? ....Camera or even turn off my iPad completely?  Recently my iPad screen had been completely locked out without my knowledge. The timing of this event was after an argument with this family member. I had to take it back to store to activate it.  Can the iPad be controled from a different location?

Comment: change your password

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the [Find my iPad enabled](https://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my-iphone.html), one can use that feature (from another device while knowing your password) to lock it remotely.

> Activation Lock.
>
> Activation Lock is designed to prevent anyone from using your iPhone,
>   iPad, or iPod touch if you ever lose your device. It starts working
>   the moment you turn on Find My iPhone. From then on, your Apple ID and
>   password will be required before anyone can turn off Find My iPhone,
>   erase your device, or reactivate it. This can help you keep your
>   device secure, even if it’s in the wrong hands.

Answer (score 1):

> Can iPad be hacked if password's security is questionable?

**Yes**.

Everything may have been configured on your iPad so as to access and control it remotely and from everywhere.

1. Change your password.
2. Change this password on every other place or computer you were using this spoiled password.
3. Check that every form of sharing setting wasn't turned on.